# Как отпарсить IP и положить в массив

Tags: php

Есть ответ от оборудования https://pastebin.com/VavtUJpz

Я начал так `$x= explode("------\r\n", str_replace('', '', $output));`

Нужно выделить IP address: `100.69.0.255`. Их там много подобных и Interface: GigabitEthernet0/21

Положить всё в массив, чтоб удобней было пробегать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой вариант подойдёт?

```
$result = array();
$pattern = '%Device\sID.+?(\IP\saddress:\s[\d\.]+).+?(\Interface:\s[\w]+\/\w+).+?Version%s';
$string = 'REN-24-AFGSD-3-t510................';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach($matches as $item) {
    $result[] = array(
        $item[1], $item[2]
    );
}

var_dump($result);
```

Можете улучшить, или поправить регулярку как Вам нужно.